# Calculating Hashrate / Threads correlating to Average Block Time

Tags: mining-pools, mining-theory, miner-configuration, block-interval

Wondering if anyone can provide some detailed fact based information on how pool mining using Fixed Difficulty affects the probability of `N` number of shares found over `T` time given the variables `X` Hashrate / `C` Threadcount.

**Example**

- Pool mining a cryptocurrency which has a block interval of 1 minute.
- CPU mining using a 48 core machine.
- When 46 cores are used for a single instance of your mining program, a hashrate of 6 kH/s is achieved.
- Setting a fixed difficulty for your miner, you set the config to only attempt to solve shares with a difficulty of > 5,000,000.

**Question**

- Given that luck is in fact a variable of whether or not a share will be found in time for the pool to record the share and credit you the pool side hashes; how do block intervals, specifically short block intervals of 1 min or 30 seconds, possibly affect the potential for more or less found and accepted shares given the hashrate of the system.
- With a short block interval, would setting up 46 instances of the mining program, each with its own CPU core affinity of 1 thread per instance, result in a greater chance of finding more overall shares over the long term?
- Considering the system may likely not find a share even when all threads are used in one instance at 6000 kH/s, and luck is a factor and variable in the shares one would find:
- Would running the 46 instances at 1 thread and each thus having a 1/46th kH/s hashrate possibly yield more fixed difficulty > 5M sized shares, due to the fact that the block interval is so short?
- My reason for asking is even a 1 thread instance running at 1/46th the hashrate has a chance of finding a share before the overall network solves the next 30 second block.
- Due to the short block time, your system would thus be running 46 instances, and thus making 46 attempts to find a > 5M value share, before the pool cancels all the work done and issues your mining system a new job / getwork.
- So do these variables matter, again, when applying to cryptos with SHORT block times.
- As the likelyhood of finding a 5M or greater share is small even when all 46 threads are used in one instance producing 6000 kH/s, considering you will be reset and receive a new job / getwork roughly every 30 seconds... are there any advantages to breaking the hashrate up into many instances of lower hashrates, thus making more attempts to solve within the small slice of time before the next job / getwork is issued?

Insight, from a mathematical approach, and factoring the complex and difficult to calculate issue of probability / odds of finding a share in respect to number of attempts vs attempt strength (higher odds / hashrate).